# spring boot with p6spy sleuth traces interpretation

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud-sleuth, distributed-tracing, p6spy

We have been using spring cloud sleuth in our micoservices for tracing. We have also added enabled jdbc level spans from spring data Repository connection, fetch and query. I am seeing some weird jps traces of name `jdbc:/datasource/connection` which seem to include some of my service specific spans. I was of the view that a parent span includes only those spans as kids, which it calls.

[image]

`venderproxy`, `profile`:`fetchorganization` are my other services' grpc endpoints, why is `jdbc:/datasource/connection` span in `supplier` including some of my services under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from one of the author of p6spy.

`jdbc:/datasource/connection` span represents open connection (transaction), in this case you're most likely haven't closed the connection and calling other services? For example you might be calling other services from the method annotated with @Transactional. While it might be ok for some scenarios, it can cause issues with connection pool if you're holding connection open for 12s.

Comment: have you an example to setup spring cloud sleuth with p6spy please ?

Comment: The library is `autoconfigured1, in itself, so you do not need any code, just addling the dependency in classpath is enough. Please follow the steps here: https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator. @AbdelghaniRoussi